# Adding and Positioning drawable in drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a splash screen which look like this on all screens:
[image: how I want resource to look like]
I want two images at two corners. This should be inside the drawable because it is background drawable of a splashscreen.

I could do it on android devices with API >= 23 using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:gravity="left|bottom"
          android:height="100dp"
          android:width="100dp"
          android:bottom="30dp"/>

    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:gravity="bottom|right"
          android:height="80dp"
          android:width="80dp"
          android:bottom="43dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

But on other devices, the drawable looks like this:

[image: how it appears on API < 23]

Comment: Can you try to put this `<item>...<bitmap
       android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
  </item>`

Comment: how shall I change the size? It gave the same result

Comment: What API Level is the second device using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `layer-list` to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:bottom="30dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:bottom="43dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Also make sure, if you are going to use different images, make sure you put those in the different folders :

> hdpi ldpi mdpi xhdpi xxhdpi